# Calculating velocities of 2 squares after collision

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision, elasticity

If I have 2 squares each with random velocities, and both with the same mass, would it be possible to calculate their velocities after a collision, and how would I do so?

Comment: Do you mean squares or spheres?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible . The only condition is that no mechanical energy must be lost.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, I was actually looking for how to do it though, and have edited my question.

Comment: I will tell ypu how to do it . Since no mechanical energy is lost the mechanical energy of the system remains the same . Also because no external forces are applied to your system the total momentum of the system remains the same ( always assuming that the contact between the 2 spheres happened instantly). I am letting you think first for a while on how you will solve it . If you still cant I will give you a mathematical description it ok?( despite the fact I really hate math)

Comment: How would I calculate the velocities after the collision happened, and how would the energy be distributed on contact?

Comment: Assume your 2 spheres have the same distance from the ground and they move only horizontally.                        We say that the first sphere is m1 and has a velocity of u1 .The second sphere is m2 and has a velocity of u2 .   1/2m1*u1^2 + 1/2m2*u2^2 = 1/2m1*u1'^2+1/2m2*u2'^2 since no energy is lost

Comment: m1*u1 + m2*u2 = m1*u1'+m2*u2' from the law of conservatipn of total momentum if no external force is applied

Comment: We assumed that no energy is lost.If the contact didnt happen instantly then some of the energy would be lost

Comment: I'm actually trying to calculate the velocities of squares, not spheres.

Comment: It is the same thing

Comment: What an answer now their is no difference between spheres and cubes

Comment: No tĥere is not if the force is applied at the mass center

Comment: @MaxDestiny: you should really incorporate much of the information in the comments in your actual answer.